# How to calculate sensor power consumption in Android

Tags: java, android, sensors

[getPower()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#getPower%28%29) returns the power in mA used by a sensor while in use:

Now, I need to calculate how much battery is used by the registration of the sensor.

Does he value returned by getPower() indicate the mAH (mA per HOUR) or something else?
If yes, is there a way to get the battery mAH in order to calculate the % of battery used by the sensor?

Comment: So, what you want to know is whether it is cheaper to leave the sensor on always or start it only when needed and stop it when not needed? Right? I ask because that is what I would want to know. :)

Comment: Sensors power consumption depends very mauth on Sensor delay rate... so you can't use this method to calculate real consumption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something quite related has been discussed in Google groups not too long ago. You can find the [full thread here](https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/6069056189b02d29) for reference.

A small excerpt from the last reply in that thread, which should answer your question more or less:

> (...) the battery capacity is always given in terms of mAH. (...) What
>   matters is how long a battery can supply a given current at its
>   rated voltage. 3800mAH means that it can supply 3800mA for 1 hour.
>   Knowing this it makes sense now that the API is providing the current
>   drain as a metric of power consumption. You can now calculate how much
>   effect it will have on the battery life as a function of time.

Comment: I've already read that thread, but nowhere in the Android developer guide is stated that mA is mAH.

Comment: That's exactly what is clarified in the group: it *isn't*. What that means in terms of what you can then use it for is explained in the quote above. For a more detailed explanation about the difference (and possibly some insight in the math involved) I'd like to point you to [this excellent external post](http://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showpost.php?s=215ea758ee37b4b7a0b29dc07d445273&p=9015084&postcount=12).

Comment: Could you make an example? If the sensor uses 0,75mA, and my battery is of 1650mAH, what % of battery drain there would be if the sensor is costantly active for 24 hours?

Comment: I am no physics wonder, but based on the units, a naive answer should be a no-brainer: `(0.75*24)/1650*100 = ~1.1%`. Do note that, generally, a battery discharge rate is not constant and dependent on lots of external factors. //Edit: another very basic example following these same rules is given [here](http://www.physicsforums.com/archive/index.php/t-130780.html).

Comment: That's the same calcule I've done, but I was not sure it was so, because of the answer given in that group. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: I have a doubt like getPower() method,will it give the absolute power consumed by the sensor component or aggregate of the power consumed Sensor+ CPU computation + SensorService processing etc(aggregate power consumption from hardware to the app)?