# Any App to monitor what sensors or CPU drain the battery life?

Tags: android, google-play

I have a Android application which i use almost all the sensors and some heavy computation algorithms. It drains out the battery in 4,5 hrs. But i need to find out which sensors or CPU users the battery? And application or any mechanism to know this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any app that measures sensor-specific battery drain, but to measure **drain per app**, the following options could work:

- [SystemPanel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.systempanel.r1)
- The simpler, built-in battery monitor: `Settings` → `System` → `About Phone` → `Battery usage`.

If you'd like to program your own **drain-per-sensor**-monitor, you could refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10293713/920200), regarding the API-function `getPower()`, which shows power consumption per sensor.