# Which motion sensor would consume less battery

Tags: android, performance, accelerometer, android-sensors, motion-detection

As long as my app is active, I need to detect movement, meaning, when the device has started to move. I'm requesting updates in a fixed frequency, and the tracking of sensors is working when the device screen is off and unplugged (it was a huge pain to accomplish that..)

In some cases, the app could be activated for hours, and so conserving battery is an important issue.

The classic implementation is using the accelerometer sensor. But I found that for tracking tilts, I could also use all of the following sensors:

`TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`
`TYPE_GYROSCOPE`
`TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION`
`TYPE_ORIENTATION`
`TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR`

([See info here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-intro))

Are some sensors better than others in means of power consumptions?

Also: Maybe using location updates using network would be better? I'm guessing that using the location updates I could use a larger frequency of update requests, but how much power would it require compared to sensor listening?

Thanks

Comment: Not a direct answer, but look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293713/calculate-android-sensor-power-consumption Now, hopefully, you will have the tools available to answer your own question.

Comment: I would not recommend updating by network. If you have to use your wifi or data receiver once, it remains in a powered state for the next 30 to 60 seconds, depending on the device. But it depends on how many times you have to check your location.