# Accelerometer and Gyroscope and its power consumption in Android phones

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, gyroscope

I'm using accelerometer and gyroscope in my Android app. I want to profile my app for its power consumption. Lets say the app, read these two sensors every 100 millisecond, add all its three axis (x,y,z), and store them in a file.

Now I am not sure if these two sensor are always on or not ? If yes, then most of the power consumption will come from how I use or process these sensors' values in my app. So I have the following questions.

1. Are these two sensors always on or active ? (If so, any reference).
2. What does then the register and deregister does ? If they are always on,
   then it won't make any difference to deregister them, at least in
   terms of power consumption.

**Background or reasoning behind these questions:** 
Gyroscope consumes more power than accelerometer (based on my analysis, its 4-6 times higher). Now if these sensors are always on then I can use them both in my app because my app is not the reason for the power consumption caused by the active status of these sensors. My app will be responsible for the power consumption due to the way I use these sensor values, and how often I read them. However, if these are disabled or off (consuming no power at all), then I have to make a careful decision if I want to use them or not because when I register them, then I am also increasing the power consumption due to their active status in addition to the processing their values.

Comment: The question is `what could you do if this is still consuming power?` If you remove your listener, you will reduce the comsumtion (has state before). But you don't have any access to physicly stop those sensors to run so what do you want to do ? The CPU cost to receive these events at this rate is quite consumer

Comment: @AxelH I agree that if I remove my listener, the power consumption due to the data processing will be reduced. However, I am curious about the the status of these sensors when no app is using them. It can help me in making my design decision if I want to use both or one sensors. If lets gyroscope and accelerometer are always on, then I would like to use both in my app. However, if not, then I may not use gyroscope because it consumes way more than accelerometer in terms power.

Comment: It makes sense now! :) You could made some test, by killing all unwanted apps (those that use the sensors) then comparing the power consumed before and after you activate the sensors listener (but this would be difficult because there might be OS process using the sensors, so this might not be really conclusive. See the following to see the consumption. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293713/calculate-android-sensor-power-consumption

Comment: @AxelH I checked the link but there is no clear answer on this issue. The mystery still remains if these sensors in general remain always active or not.

Comment: It wasn't an answer but a way to check yourself the consumption.

Comment: AlexH Ahhh okay. For that, I have used other apps which reports these sensors' power consumption. However, I cannot be sure if its being used by any apps. I still got power consumption values for it when not used by any apps which I know of. It also indicates that these sensors might be active all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly as addition to the answer from Andriy Omelchenko with some more links:

1.
This is broadly and "manufacturer independent" documented in [Androids Architecture Documentation in the Sensors Section](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/). Specifically that [Accelerometer and Gyroscope](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensor-types.html#composite_sensor_type_summary) are handled as [non-wakup](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/suspend-mode.html#non-wake-up_sensors) sensors which report events continuously but may not wake up the SoC.

So **yes, you can assume these 2 sensors are always on**.

2.
*Furthermore the documentation states:* If an Application needs the data in background, it needs to hold a Wakelock - probably [the Partial](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK) Wakelock which will keep the system from going into low power/sleep mode - such that events are processed and delivered without being dropped. Obviously this will drain the battery faster.

You could imply that registering/unregistering may have a low effect on power as long as you don't keep a Wakelock.

But **in general you shouldn't assume it is useless to register/deregister sensors for power optimization** - except one-shot sensors. Not only because of the power used for processing and delivery of events to apps and the possibility of keeping the system from its sleep. It is a [Framework recommendation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html) and these are normally not without cause like the use of [register with report delay to make use of batching if possible](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/batching.html). The impact may change with different hardware or other factors.

It could also be a funny bug source if - for example - you assume that data is provided depending on the *Wakelock*: The documentation only states that for non-wake-up sensors the *driver* is not allowed to hold a Wakelock and the sensor shouldn't wake the SoC. Meaning your app could be processing events in the background or not depending on device, system, installed apps and so on.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation and reference. Its something relevant which I was looking for. After reading this, I think, these two sensor are always on. I have personally tested these sensors with and without acquiring partial lock. When I don't acquire partial lock, and the phone screen turns off, I don't get data events from these sensors even when they are registered with the listener. However, when I acquire the lock, then it reports perfectly fine even if the screen is off.

Comment: Lets wait for some time if we see any other explanation otherwise I'll accept your response as an Answer.

Comment: What I meant was what happens when another app retains a wakelock and keeps the system awake, does your app get events too or not? The events should be ignored if the CPU is sleeping but neither [Sensors CDD](https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd.html#7_3_sensors) nor system/api documentation says clearly that you won't get data even if another app retains a lock.

Comment: I haven't tested that. I can speculate that if any of the apps acquires the lock while using these sensors, then the sensor data (events) should be delivered to all apps which are listening for it unless they de-registered these sensors on onpause() or onstop() method.

Answer (score 1):

From [Official site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html): "Always make sure to disable sensors you don't need, especially when your activity is paused. Failing to do so can drain the battery in just a few hours. Note that the system will not disable sensors automatically when the screen turns off."

"Are these two sensors always on or active?" - seems this question has no general answer because it depends on hardware. Actually accelerometer and gyroscope has low power consumption, but they support by OS may consume more battery.

"What does then the register and deregister does ?" - eliminates power consumption for data processing from them.

Comment: I would think that the accelerometer has to be "on" all the time (when the display is on) or otherwise the device couldn't respond to orientation changes and rotate the UI accordingly. Apparently on many devices it's turned off when the display is turned off which then causes problems for apps that try to do anything orientation/acceleration related in the background without user interaction (like accelerometer based step counters or sleep trackers).

Comment: @Andriy Omelchenko I can understand that deregister will eliminate the power consumption due to the processing data from these sensors. However, I am not sure if this function disable these sensors. Though accelerometer has low power, gyroscope consumes much more than accelerometer. I used an app to measure this where its almost 5-6 times higher than accelerometer.

Comment: @Markus Kauppinen Are you referring to the screen orientation? if yes, that can be disabled and the screen is not oriented when we change the orientation of the phone. So does it mean that when this option is disabled then the accelerometer is also disabled ?

Comment: @zub12 I would imagine that if you specifically request accelerometer data then you will of course get it regardless of the automatic UI rotation. But I haven't checked that myself.

Comment: @Markus Kauppinen I have checked that. I still get accelerometer data when screen rotation is disabled. I am just wondering when none of app is using accelerometer, and the screen rotation is also disabled, if accelerometer is still consuming power ?

Comment: @Markus Kauppinen In general You are right, but [CDD](https://source.android.com/compatibility/cdd.html) has no requirements for power control for accelerometer or gyroscope. So it may be different.

Answer (score 1):

The accelerometer and gyroscope are *not* always on. That would be crazy - absolutely anything that draws power in a mobile device is put into a low power mode where-ever possible (no application is currently requesting it). Hence the need to register / deregister.

There isn't a strict specification to require this from hardware manufacturers, because this is a common sense optimization to increase battery life.